# Getting "Unable to determine system type - response: 500 Unknow command" when listing files on ESP8266 with Apache Commons Net

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I try to connect to FTP server in `ESP8266`. Connection is successful, but I can't get list of files on the server.

My code is:

```
FTPClient mFtpClient = new FTPClient();
mFtpClient.setConnectTimeout(10000);
mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(ip));
status = mFtpClient.login(userName, pass);
Log.e("isFTPConnected", String.valueOf(status));
if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFtpClient.getReplyCode())) {
    mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    FTPFile[] mFileArray = mFtpClient.listFiles();
    Log.e("Size", String.valueOf(mFileArray.length));
}
```

**In logical I get the error :**

> java.io.IOException: Unable to determine system type - response: 500 Unknow command.

I use Apache Commons Net FTP library. So what is wrong in my code? From `FileZilla` Windows client, I can connect. May be the reason is that in ESP is SPIFF file system? Or another one reason?

Thanks for answers, and interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server does not support `SYST` command, that the `FTPClient` needs to decide how to parse a response of `LIST` command.

Solutions are:

- If your server supports `MLSD` command, use [`mlistDir`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistDir()) instead of `listFiles`.
- Or use `System.setProperty` to set `FTP_SYSTEM_TYPE_DEFAULT` or `FTP_SYSTEM_TYPE` to suggest what directory listing format your server is using.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! My error is, that when I try to solve my problem, I replaced `mFtpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();` before connect() method, and all other trying was incorrect.

Comment: This answer also works for the similar error `java.io.IOException: Unable to determine system type - response: 550 Permission denied.`  To be clear for the second bullet, the code will look like `System.setProperty(FTPClient.FTP_SYSTEM_TYPE_DEFAULT, FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX);`